# Rules of addition of electric field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, vectors, superposition

According to the principle of superposition of Electric Fields , we know that Electric fields add using laws of vectors. However while adding the electric fields , if for example one field is generated due to repulsion between two point charges and another field is generated due to attraction between two point charges , both of them pointing in the same direction and having the same magnitude , would they cancel each other out because one is attractive and the other is repulsive, or would they add up because they’re vectors pointing in the same direction?

Comment: For vectors ( here $\vec{E}$ ) , they add up obeying $R=\sqrt{P^2+Q^2+2PQ\cos\alpha}$ ... The case of attraction or repulsion is managed by $\alpha$ ...

Comment: @Nehal thank you ! So you mean that in this case they will add up even if they’re repulsive?

Comment: they *would add up because they’re vectors pointing in the same direction.* The fact that one is attractive and one is repulsive is already taken care of in the direction, which is the direction in which a +ve test charge would move.

Comment: @sammygerbil ohh you’re right !! Now I understood the reason ! Thanks a lot :)